# Can JVM be configured to not use USRSIG1?

Tags: java, go, signals, ipc

I have an application  (Go) that creates a JVM in a child process. The application has its own use of the SIGUSR1 signal which conflicts with the JVM it seems and crashes.

Here's the only relevant log I've seen from the application:

`Warning: SIGUSR1 handler expected:0x0000000000000000  found:<application-name>`

I've tried using '-Xusealtsigs' option when spinning up the JVM but that doesn't seem have any effect on USRSIG1 or USRSIG2.

Is there any way to have to JVM not use USRSIG1?

*Note I won't be able to change the signal processing in the main application.

Comment: You may want to search [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm) for the word “signal”.  It says `-Xusealtsigs` doesn’t do anything, but it mentions two other options, `-XX:+AllowUserSignalHandlers` and `-Xrs`.

Comment: @VGR thanks for the help.

Using -XX:+AllowUserSignalHandler threw the  this error :

`fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution

[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7f9dd5b8e2b4]`

and using the **-Xrs** option didn't have any other effect.

Comment: What OS? According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html, on Linux the answer is no.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks! I was running on macOS and rhel 7.